# how to fix Missing required parameters in laravel

Tags: laravel

last night i tried and check several times tried to seek "konsuman" in my route, model, controller, database, and views.
but i found nothing. the correct value is "konsumen" but after run in browser show error

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Missing required parameters for [Route: konsumen.update]
[URI: konsumen/{konsuman}]. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs
\skh\resources\views\konsumen\edit.blade.php).
```

i check in several times to make sure its "konsumen" not "konsuman" but laravel show error like above.

is there any mistaken in my code or maybe another erorr. enclosed my complete work.

[image: konsuman shows in route list, actualy there is no konsuman. the true value is konsumen]

[image: laravel show error because can't find konsuman]

here is the [link](https://pastebin.com/jexCLU2P) of my complete code in route, model, controller, database and view.
thank you for the attention given

Answer (score 1):

You forgot add param to `route('konsumen.update')`.

It should be `route('konsumen.update', ['konsuman' => $id])`

`$id` is the id of konsumen record you're editing.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write required in kde_konsumen

```
$request->validate([
        'kde_konsumen',
        'nma_konsumen' => 'required',
        'alm_konsumen' => 'required',
        'tlp_konsumen' => 'required',
    ]);
```

to

```
$request->validate([
        'kde_konsumen' => 'required',
        'nma_konsumen' => 'required',
        'alm_konsumen' => 'required',
        'tlp_konsumen' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the form action tag value in

> edit.blade.php

to `<form action="{{ '/konsumen/'. $konsumen->kde_konsumen) }} " method="POST">`

Comment: thank you for your solution, its worked, but i tried to make the code same among other application. not mix it up. hence for other case your code wis working, but in my case not working.

Comment: just like in my description, my code (variable) or other name dont have "konsuman" but laravel display "konsuman" which this cause make the code not working. i have 5 code identically used the code above work fine. only this code error

Answer (score 0):

This is one drawback of using `resource` in laravel route. It does create all the CURD routes, but it has its own standards that you need to follow.
So when you have created

```
 Route::resource('konsumen', 'KonsumenController');
```

This in turn generated the routes that you can see in your screenshot. 
Take a look at the `update route`, it expects a parameter.
So whereever you are using `konsumen.update` route you also need to pass a parameter `konsuman`.
So it would be like this

```
route('konsumen.update', ['konsuman' => <someValue>])
```

Just like @PhucLam said

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one thing. In your controller, you are accepting the `$konsumen` model object. But you didn't define how your `$konsumen` will convert to the model object. Because from URL you are getting an id.

To solve this you need to do some settings in your `RouteServiceProvide` class. Below is the code you need to add in your provider:-

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::model('konsumen', \App\Konsumen::class);

    parent::boot();
}
```

After this, your code will work.